# Looking for GIS dataset for Japan with attributes in English

Tags: data, japan

I have found some [GIS data for Japan](http://nlftp.mlit.go.jp/ksj-e/gml/gml_datalist.html) but the location attributes (prefecture, city names etc) are in Japanese. Anyone know where I could find this data in English, I could get it translated but it would take a long long time.

Comment: I have worked with some of these data sets, mainly hydrography, and was really impressed by Google translator results

Answer (score 4):

OpenStreetMap is another possibility for place names and administrative boundaries (For boundaries, you might find GADM easier to use though, as per Sebastian's suggestion).

OSM uses the **`name`** tag in the local language world-wide, but in Japan you'll find many places will have English translations in the **`name:en`** tag.

Answer (score 3):

The administrative units can be found at [gadm.org](http://gadm.org/). Some older city names (1995) are at the [Harvard Asia Center](http://www.fas.harvard.edu/~chgis/japan/datasets.html).